# Do orthogonal polynomials determine the moments of their orthogonality measure?

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials, moment-problem

I am currently learning about the *inverse problem for orthogonal polynomials* for orthogonality measures supported on the real line. 
My question is not about finding the orthogonality measure from the moments but finding the moments from the recurrence coefficients.

> **Background**. This is the problem of finding the orthogonality measure
>   $\mu$ for the sequence of orthogonal polynomials $(P_n(x))_n$  such
>   that $$ \int_{supp(\mu)}P_n(x)P_m(x)d\mu(x) = h_n \delta_{n,m}, $$
>   given the recurrence coefficients $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ and 
>   $(b_n)_{n\geq 1}$ that the polynomials satisfy 
>   $$ x P_n(x) = P_{n+1}(x) + a_n P_n(x) + b_n P_{n-1}(x), \quad P_{-1}(x):=0. $$ 
>   where we have chosen **monic** polynomials so that our recursion leads to a unique sequence of
>   polynomials where $\deg(P_n)=n$.
>
> Now if we have the *moments* of the measure $\mu$, 
>   $$ m_k := \int_{supp(\mu)} x^k d\mu(x), $$  with $k\geq 0$, 
>   we can determine the
>   monic polynomials and equivalently their recurrence  coefficients
>   uniquely. However given the moments we might not be able to determine
>   the measure. We might be dealing with an indeterminate measure
>   problem.
>
> For simplicity we should restrict ourselves to the case of absolutely
>   continuous measures. This means there exists a continuous function $w(x)$
>   such that $d\mu(x)=w(x)dx$.

**Question**

Given the recurrence coefficients (or the polynomials or the square norms $h_n$) can we uniquely determine the moments? And if not, what restrictions
can we use to make them unique?

**What I have tried so far**

I have two points. The first of which seems to indicate that the moments
are not determined. The second seems to restrict the apparent freedom shown
in point 1.

**1**

Given all the square norms $h_n$, we seem to have some freedom in how to take the moments since
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
h_0 &= m_0 \\
h_1 &= m_2 + v_{1,1}m_1 + v_{1,0}m_0 \\
h_2 &= m_4 + v_{2,3}m_3 + v_{2,2}m_2 + v_{2,1}m_1 + v_{2,0}m_0,\\
& \text{etc.}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where the $v_{n,k}$ are just some constants determined by the monic polynomial coefficients.
This leads me to believe that for a given $h_n$, both $(m_{2n}, m_{2n-1})$ as
well as a **distinct** $(\widetilde{m}_{2n},\widetilde{m}_{2n-1})$ could lead to the same
$h_n$ as long as
$$
m_{2n} + v_{n,n-1} m_{2n-1} = \widetilde{m}_{2n} + v_{n,n-1} \widetilde{m}_{2n-1}.
$$

So it seems that given all $h_n$, we need to fix one extra parameter
for each $n$ to dispense of the ambiguity of the moments $(m_{2n},m_{2n-1})$.

**2**

However there seems to be less freedom than is immediately apparent. We cannot, for example, just take $m_{2k}=0$ for $k>0$. This would imply that
the orthogonality measure is anti-symmetric. This can't be true in general, right?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is conventional to normalise the polynomials ($h_n = 1$) so that the recurrence coefficients (not the same $a$'s and $b$'s as yours) are the elements of a Jacobi Matrix
$$A=        \begin{bmatrix}
        a_0 & b_0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
       b_0 & a_1 & b_1 & 0 & \cdots\\
        0 & b_1 & a_2 & b_2 & \cdots \\
       0 & 0 & b_2 & a_3  & \cdots \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
        \end{bmatrix}.
$$
The moments are then $(\delta_0, A^n\delta_0)$ where $\{\delta_i\}$ is the natural basis. See Barry Simon's [The Classical Moment Problem as a Self-Adjoint
Finite Difference Operator](http://www.math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/270.pdf#page=12) , around eq. (1.16).